# How do you update a widget using Metronome.periodic?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app displays food orders that users from another app generate when they order food. The `Order` class  has a field `timestamp`(from firestore). I'm using this timestamp as an anchor in   the [Metronome.periodic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/quiver.async/Metronome/Metronome.periodic.html) constructor. And for the duration I'm using a minute.

```
Metronome.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1),anchor: order.timestamp.toDate());
```

What I need to do is show how long ago it has been since the order has been generated and show this in my app. So I'm trying to update a Text widget every minute. How can I update widget using Metronome.periodic. Or is this even a good approach?

Comment: Seems like a workable approach. Just `listen` to the `Metronome` and call `setState`.

Comment: I don't really want to use a stateful widget. Probably should of pointed that out.

Comment: You have to update the state somehow every minute. I don't think there is a way to get around it. Why don't you want to use a stateful widget?

Comment: the guy I'm handing the code in to doesn't like it! Anyway I've more confidence this is a good approach, thanks.

Comment: No problem! I really don't think there is any way of getting around using a stateful widget or a builder, which  essentially does the same thing. The best you can do is to just isolate what has to be rebuilt as best you can.

Comment: how else can you not use setState() and get away with it?? everything uses setState behind the scenes i guess!!